# Textual geolocation

Tags: python, geolocation, geocoding

I need to geolocate a series of entries in a single-country development projects database. I have a brief synopsis for each project within which I would like to identify municipalities (or even larger political entities) to allow me to geolocate each project later on with the GoogleMaps API.

I am trying to extract the geographic information without using natural language processing. I am not keen to use NLP because the project are located in small villages, whose name I can obtain from other sources.

I was considering splitting the text on spaces, and trying to find matches using a Python vocabulary in which the value is the name of the village and the key is the name of the village split at spaces.

Example:

"Project X has been built in The Hague, The Netherlands". 
Would give me: "The Hague"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use NLP :-) or at least some algorithms related to NLP.
Here you can find list of cities/towns having more than 500 citizens with information about GPS coordinates, region(s), country and continent http://www.geonames.org/ or http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt 
I would use these data to build very light-weight Name Entity Recognition using https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/ algorithms.
And after that you can have a nice and neat "tree"/hierarchy of village - small region - bigger region - country - continent (maybe even with GPS coordinates if I am not wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Try https://geocode.xyz/textscan

https://geocode.xyz/?scantext=Project%20X%20has%20been%20built%20in%20The%20Hague,%20The%20Netherlands&geoit=XML

```
<geodata>
<match>
<location>The Hague,NL</location>
<latt>52.06805</latt>
<longt>4.29647</longt>
<confidence>0.2</confidence>
<MentionIndices>32</MentionIndices>
<matchtype>locality</matchtype>
</match>
</geodata>
```